# CasperJS clear input field

Tags: input, phantomjs, casperjs

Is there any way to clear a input field with CasperJS or PhantomJS before filling it?

I have tried `sendKeys('input_field', "data", clear:true);` and `fill` functions, but all of them just append the input field and don't clear it before.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The option is called `reset`:

```
casper.sendKeys('input_field', "data", { reset: true} );
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I couldn't find it in the doc though. Where did you find it ?

Comment: Wow, don't know how I missed that. I thought I had looked very carefully. THanks !